# Are session/context variables passed by reference or value?

Tags: django

Suppose I have a variable x which is very large. When reading x as a session variable from request, or passing it as a context variable to a template, are you reading/writing a reference to x, or the actual value of x? Is there a difference in this between session and context variables?

The reason I am asking, is that if x really is very large, then reading/writing it by value will be very slow, and so I would need to make sure I am only reading/writing a pointer to it.

Comment: Without meaning to sound flippant... If you're storing an object in your session that is so large that a memcopy is the cause of a bottleneck, there's something very wrong with your architecture.

Comment: How else should I be storing such user-specific data? Session is the only way I know so far!

Comment: First of all, let's get some numbers. If we're talking kilobytes or megabytes, don't worry about it. Seriously. Memory copy speeds are measured on the order of gigabytes/second. So your performance hit is measured in microseconds at worst. A larger concern here is that you'd run out of memory with enough sessions. If you're talking more than a few megabytes, you should be storing the data somewhere out of memory and using the session to store an Id which indicates the data to load. A simple example is to write the object to disk and store the filename in the session.